# Row Reducing with Imaginary Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

So I have the system  $$
        X' =\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        -k & -b
        \end{pmatrix} X
$$

where I assume $$ 0 \le b < 2 \sqrt{k} $$

which results in one complex eigenvalue $$ \lambda = (1/2) (-b + i\sqrt{b^2 - 4k}) $$ 
However, when I try to row-reduce to get the corresponding eigenvector, I keep getting the identity matrix, meaning my eigenvector is $$ (0, 0) $$ Is this correct, because I've been pouring over my steps and can't find any errors. However this would mean the solution is $$ X = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the initial constraints, $$ b^2 - 4*k < 0 $$ which creates a complex eigenvalue

Comment: The identity matrix has every vector as an eigenvector, not just $(0,0)$. Try any other vector, the eigenvalue is $1$

Comment: So how do I format that in the general solution I understand that I would be breaking up the real and imaginary parts, but if every vector is an eigenvector, do I just choose convenient eigenvectors?

Comment: You have two complex eigenvalues.  The $+$ sign before the $i$ should be $\pm$.  Each one will have an eigenvector, which will have complex components.  No, you shouldn't be breaking into real and imaginary parts, because you are operating over $\Bbb C^2$

Comment: Is it correct to say that the row reduction using those eigenvalues is the identity matrix though? I just don't understand how I pull an eigenvector from that to generate my solution.

Comment: An eigenvector by definition has to be nonzero

Comment: No, you will diagonalize the matrix to have the eigenvalues on he diagonal, so it will not be proportional to the identity matrix.  Each eigenvalue will have its own eigenvector.  It works just like the real case except that the $2 \times 2$ blocks in the real case that come from a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues can be diagonalized over $\Bbb C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are row-reducing the original matrix. You need to row-reduce the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        -k & -b
        \end{pmatrix} - \lambda I$$ - the null space of that difference is the set of eigenvalues you want.